# Apache Commons Crypto - Getting IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: apache, encryption, aes

I am trying to use the following method to handle both encryption and decryption of AES data using Apache Commons Crypto. Encryption is working fine. But when I try to decrypt the data I just encrypted, I am getting this block size error, which I don't totally understand since I'm setting the blocksize to 1024, which of course is a multiple of 16.

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length (with padding) not multiple of 16 bytes
```

Here is my code:

```
        final int bufferSize = 1024;
    try {
      this.cryptoCipher.init(cipherMode, this.secretKeySpec, this.ivParameterSpec);
        ByteBuffer inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
        ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);
        inBuffer.put(getUTF8Bytes(dataToBeEncrypted));
        inBuffer.flip();
        int updateBytes = this.cryptoCipher.update(inBuffer, outBuffer);
        int finalBytes = this.cryptoCipher.doFinal(inBuffer, outBuffer);   <<<< EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE!!!
        byte[] encoded = new byte[updateBytes + finalBytes];
        outBuffer.flip();
        outBuffer.duplicate().get(encoded);
        encryptedDecryptedData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encoded);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.logp(Level.SEVERE, MODULE_NAME, methodName, "encountered exception: {0}", exc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES has one block size: 16-bytes so setting the block size to another value is an error. But you are not setting the block size, just creating a buffer of (in this case) 1024 bytes.

Most implementations accept an array and will internally process the input a block at a time. But the input must be an exact multiple of the block size and that is accomplished with padding, usually [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), and by an option handles this automatically by adding on encryption and removing on decryption.

Comment: Thanks, Zaph. I am using 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding' as the transform value. I have seen elsewhere that this should be automatically converted to PKCS7 inyernally. However, I just tried changing it to 'AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding', and now I'm getting an error:  
    Caused by: javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Padding: PKCS7Padding not implemented
  
I'm using IBM Java 7.1.

Comment: Use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, PKCS#5 padding is a subset of PKCS#7 but in all implementations seen it also supports PKCS#7. Since many of the libraries pre-date AES they continue to use the same padding constant.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The problem is, that's what I've been using all along, and that's giving me my error. So I'm kind of lost at this point. Please see my "answer" below (because for whatever reason, comments never format correctly for me).

Comment: I found my problem. I was Base64 encoding the outgoing encrypted value, but wasn't decoding the incoming data. Thanks again for your help!